# Anime where an orphan boy gets a gold forearm brace with a red gem and befriends a prince

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I saw this cartoon/anime a long time ago where there was a spoilt prince and he treated people in a bad way and in a parallel story there was an orphan who saves an old man who gives him a golden arm brace with a red stone and an inscription on it. He later befriends the prince and they protect the village together. One of them sacrifices his life if I remember correctly.

I have been trying to find it for over 10 years now with no luck... I couldnt have been the only person who saw that on TV that day.
If anyone knows anything let me know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, do you recall the hair colour of either boy?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying! I saw it in between 2005-2008.. I dont exactly remember the hair colour but I would place my bet on black. I remember the arm brace correctly cause I made one for myself out of chart paper XD. The gem was circular and the inscription was a quote

Comment: Was the animation 2D or 3D? Did the arm brace confer any powers on the orphan boy? And what did the boys protect the village from?

Comment: The animation was 2D. The arm brace did give the orphan some kind of powers. The village was attacked by some hydra type monster I guess, the battle was near a water body.  The prince sacrifices himself in the battle.